# Chrome / Firefox extension like Safari 5's 'Reader' feature

Tags: macos, firefox, google-chrome, browser-addons

i love the new Safari 5 'Reader' feature, but Safari is not my main browser. I mostly use Chrome, and sometimes Firefox. Does anybody know if there's an extension that does the same? I've been using Arc90's [Readability](http://lab.arc90.com/experiments/readability/), which is very nice, but isn't quite the same (it doesn't do multi-page, for instance).

Comment: Readability *is* the default answer here.

Comment: Not sure how comparable the feature set is, but I've been using [Instapaper Text bookmarklet](http://www.instapaper.com/text) for this purpose. Similar to Readability, says the site.

Comment: Yeah, Instapaper is pretty great too, but it isn't quite as nice as Safari's Reader. That also doesn't do multi-page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might like to take a look at the [iReader](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ppelffpjgkifjfgnbaaldcehkpajlmbc?hl=en) Chrome extension. It will support multi-page articles, and there's a [version available for Firefox as well](http://www.samabox.com/blog/2010/07/say-hello-to-ireader-for-firefox/).

Comment: Wonderful! It mimics Safari's 'Reader' button very well. I wrote a little blogpost about this plugin. Hopefully other people will pick it up too. http://www.haykranen.nl/2010/08/19/ireader-plugin-mimics-safaris-reader-option/

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try a combination of Readability and [AutoPagerize](http://autopagerize.net/) to make that happen. AP first, so the content is all loaded, and then Readability to get it displayed nicely.

*P.S.* For a lot of sites, you can click through to the "Print" view and then enable Readability on that, as the "Print" view is often the full article/post.

Answer (score 0):

[Readability Redux](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jggheggpdocamneaacmfoipeehedigia)

> Readability is a simple tool that makes reading on the Web more enjoyable by removing the cluter around what you're reading.
>
> [image]